# JSON stringify nested object

Tags: json, ajax

I have to send data from view to controller using ajax. 
Here is my class and I should send JSON appropriate to that class structure. Jackson will convert JSON to my class

```
public class RealEstateAgencyDTO extends BaseEntityDTO {

/** The name. */
private String name;

/** The description. */
private String description;

/** The site. */
private String site;

/** The phone number. */
private String phone;

/** The address of the office. */
private AddressDTO address;


public final String getName() {
    return name;
}

public final void setName(final String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
}

public final String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public final void setDescription(final String newDescription) {
    this.description = newDescription;
}

public final String getSite() {
    return site;
}

public final void setSite(final String newSite) {
    this.site = newSite;
}

public final String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public final void setPhone(final String newPhone) {
    this.phone = newPhone;
}

public final AddressDTO getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public final void setAddress(final AddressDTO newAddress) {
    this.address = newAddress;
}
```

}

how should I use JSON.stringify() in order to get such an object that correspond my structure

I've tried to use smth like that but it doesn't work

```
var address = JSON.stringify({
                country: $('#country').val(),
                region: $('#description').val(),
                postalCode: $('#postalCode').val(),
                locality: $('#locality').val(),
                additionalInfo: $('#additionalInfo').val()
            });

            var data = {
                agencyName: $('#agencyName').val(),
                description: $('#description').val(),
                phoneNumber: $('#phoneNumber').val(),
                webSite: $('#webSite').val(),
                address: address
            };

             $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                   url: "registerAgency",
                   data:  JSON.stringify(data),
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                       alert("data saved")
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       console.log(errorThrown);
                   }
               })
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating it. Don't stringify until the very end, otherwise you will end up with json inside of json, which is unlikely to be useful in any situation.

```
var address = {
    country: $('#country').val(),
    region: $('#description').val(),
    postalCode: $('#postalCode').val(),
    locality: $('#locality').val(),
    additionalInfo: $('#additionalInfo').val()
};

var data = {
    agencyName: $('#agencyName').val(),
    description: $('#description').val(),
    phoneNumber: $('#phoneNumber').val(),
    webSite: $('#webSite').val(),
    address: address
};

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "registerAgency",
    data:  JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("data saved")
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the address member on object data is already stringified. The subsequent call will treat this as a string value (which it is!) JSON.stringify() will handle nested objects fine.